# Expanding reputation is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, profile-page, meta

When trying to 'expand' the reputation (by clicking on the arrow) it shows the AJAX loader.

But nothing happens. It doesn't even make a request to the server :P

[cannot expand rep http://img46.imageshack.us/img46/2188/expandrep.png](http://img46.imageshack.us/img46/2188/expandrep.png)

This is for both expanding the question and the date.

It looks like somebody screw up the javascript (no need to point fingers ;) ):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined
>
> auser.js:1
>
> f.event.dispatchjquery.min.js:3
>
> f.event.add.h.handle.i

[JS error http://img843.imageshack.us/img843/6936/jserror.png](http://img843.imageshack.us/img843/6936/jserror.png)

**UPDATE**

Tested in both Chrome Canary and stable

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: @kiamlaluno platform?

Comment: I am using Safari 5.1.2 on Mac OS X 10.7.2; if the location can make the difference, I am in Italy.

Comment: Works for me in chrome and IE 9.

Comment: @jadarnel27 it was fixed so now it works for everyone. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's due to upgrading jQuery to 1.7.1 - there is this line of code:

```
var p = $(this).closest("td").attr("id");
```

The `.attr()` was replaced by `.prop()` as of jQuery 1.6 so combined with the fact the parent `<td>` has no ID, it broke the code: prior to 1.6 it returned empty string.. after 1.6 it returns `undefined` value.

[Test case with jQuery 1.5.2](http://jsfiddle.net/LxKV2/)

[Test case with jQuery 1.7.1](http://jsfiddle.net/LxKV2/1/)

[Test case for fixed code](http://jsfiddle.net/LxKV2/2/).

Comment: @balpha Now I feel bad that I posted [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115390/when-is-so-going-to-upgrade-their-jquery-version) :P Please don't tell them where I live :)

Comment: LOL! The irony... :D

Comment: well at least it is stated clearly in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) so I'm no the one to blame (this is just in my defense of course :D ).

Comment: Yes indeed and they probably changed this in the "main" JS code, that error occurs in rather "minor" file that was probably overlooked.

Comment: This isn't really true. `.attr` was not replaced by `.prop`; they're different methods with different use cases, and `.attr` is still the correct one to use here. The actuall issue here is that while the DOM specification says `getAttribute` should return an empty string for non-existent attributes, pretty much all browsers return `null` instead -- which jQuery then "normalizes" to undefined (of course `null` would've caused the same issue). `elem.id`, however, is always a string (even if empty). That's why using `prop` instead of `attr` worked. /cc @PeeHaa

Comment: @balpha thanks, didn't delve *so* deep into it now I learned some new things. :)