# "Add Comment" button permanently disabled by comment floodguard

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

When I try to write a comment in quick succession after another, I get the expected "you gotta wait 15 seconds" notification in orange.

That's fine; I can wait. Ish.

But the "Add Comment" button is also disabled, and it cannot be re-enabled; I have to copy my comment to the clipboard, refresh the entire page, then try again.

Annoying.

(This appears to be new since at most a couple of days ago.)

(Firefox 8.0.1, Windows 7)

Comment: Ok, I'm seeing it now too.  The button is disabled but you can still submit your comment by pressing enter.  On FF 8.0 on Win7x64.

Comment: @balpha: Ta duck :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is another [`.attr()` versus `.prop()` issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117773/expanding-reputation-is-broken/117776#117776) from the [jQuery 1.7 upgrade](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115390/when-is-so-going-to-upgrade-their-jquery-version/115428#115428).

The function used by `StackExchange.helpers.enableSubmitButton()` needs to be updated to toggle the disabled property, instead of setting the attribute:

```
$(i).find('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', h);
```

or (since there's probably never more than one submit button anyway):

```
$(i).find('input[type="submit"]')[0].disabled = h;
```

Comment: I'm beginning to see why jQuery wanted to start being explicit about the differences between attributes and properties. Unfortunately, "consistency" is not a word that comes to mind when looking through the implementations of `prop` and `attr`. In jQuery 1.5, `.attr("disabled", "")` comes down to `elem.disabled = ""`, which does the right thing. In 1.7, anything that's not `=== false` is considered true. That's what we get for being good citizens previously and using "" instead of `false` :(

Comment: Yeah, they unfortunately opened a rather large can of worms by originally conflating the two. Despite the upgrade-related problems its caused, I am at least happy that the 1.7 behaviour is now what's expected for modifying the attribute.

Comment: Almost :) Had we used `false` in the first place, it would still be wrong, but work.

Comment: Well, I was willing to consider `.attr('disabled', false)` the same as `.removeAttribute('disabled')` :P