# Update site to jQuery1.7.2

Tags: discussion, feature-request, jquery

Currently SE uses [jQuery v1.7.1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115390/when-is-so-going-to-upgrade-their-jquery-version), but [1.7.2 is out](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/03/21/jquery-1-7-2-released/) with a few more bug fixes.

1.7.2 is out on the Google CDN now.

Comment: Do you actually believe that an update to a major library on SO is as simple as that? You don't think that some time should be spent doing testing and proper QA before hand?

Comment: Are there specific bugs you're experiencing that you believe upgrading to 1.7.2 will fix?

Comment: I'm pretty sure jQuery updates itself last time I checked.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: fun fact, it uses jQuery to do so.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: I'm not so, last thing I heard was that balpha struggled hard to update it last time...I'm sure he'd not so fond of automatic updates to jQuery.

Comment: @Kobobby: It just doesn't like him.

Answer (score 11):

Why? [What would it fix](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/03/21/jquery-1-7-2-released/)?

We need a reason for upgrading any of our libraries/dependencies.  If it fixes something, or allows us to do something better and/or faster, sure...but upgrading for the sake of upgrading isn't wise.

We're bug-free at the moment (AFAIK, related to jQuery), upgrading can *only* break something (and has, every time).  It's not that breaks aren't worth it...if we get something from the upgrade then we deal with the breaks.  If we're *not* getting something from the upgrade then it's just wasted time tracking down bugs...time we could be using to add more awesome to the site.

Comment: I dunno about that whole "more awesome" business; if waffles [meta-tag:status-completed]s one more long-dead/declined [meta-tag:feature-request], someone might have a heart attack.

Comment: -1 not enough jQuery

Comment: There are a few bug fixes, which may or may not pertain to SO; I don't know every single line of JS on your site, sorry!  But here are a few highlights of the fixes:<br>

Comment: Animate negative margins: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11469

Comment: jQuery.param() mistakes wrapped primitives for deep objects http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10466

Comment: @tom Nick *did* link you to the blog post that lists all the bugs that were fixed. Pretty sure he knows that they didn't increment the version number for no reason. This isn't Google Chrome, after all. I think you missed the point: there's no good reason to upgrade, since things are working just fine now. Upgrading is *more likely* to break things than *not* upgrading.