# Why does Stack Exchange use such an old version of jQuery? (1.7.1)

Tags: feature-request, google-chrome, jquery

When I Use the Retire.js Chrome plugin I get a warning that the jQuery 1.7.1 (from November 2011) included on Stack Exchange is vulnerable to 'Selector interpreted as HTML' (jQuery bug [11290](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11290))

Besides this vulnerability which may or may not apply, is it not time to upgrade to a newer version ?

Feature request please :)

Comment: related, but old : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115390/when-is-so-going-to-upgrade-their-jquery-version

Comment: Balpha says it himself: if it ain't broken, don't fix it.

Comment: But if it has a possible security flaw ? (I am no jQuery expert)

Comment: Do they even use that part of jQuery?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Indeed they do e.g. $('#post-form') 14 times on this page

Comment: @rjdkolb: It *appears*, superficially, as though the bug is really only relevant if there's a `<` (parent selector) character somewhere in there. Does SE code do anything with those?

Comment: @NathanTuggy, not that I can see directly. I asked a question on Stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33756121/selector-interpreted-as-html-on-my-website-can-an-attacker-easily-exploit-this 
With the dynamic nature of Stack Exchange, this may be possible.
(Again I am not a jQuery expert)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284996/were-updating-jquery-to-1-12-4-tomorrow?cb=1